# If I build a Spring app on App Engine, will it use multithreading by default or can it be configured to?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

According to the [latest App Engine news](http://goo.gl/8vMfM), Java apps can minimize the number of instance hours they use by enabling multi-threading - which will allow them to use more resources per instance-hour.

If I build a Spring app on App Engine, will it use multithreading by default to optimize its resource use?

Or is there something I need to do to configure it to take advantage of this App Engine feature?

Answer (score 2):

Servlet multithreading on AppEngine is off by default. You can simply enable it by adding a `<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>` element to `appengine-web.xml`.

In this case your servlets must be thread safe: basically this means that they should not have internal state (fields) or access to the state data must be synchronized.

About Spring: I'm not familiar with Spring internals, so I could not say if it's thread safe.